# How to uninstall antivirus on many computers?

Tags: windows-server-2008

People I have Active Directory Windows Server 2008 with 100 pc with Windows 7 in my network , I have installed free antivirus "PC Tools" ,can I remotely uninstall it from all computers  ? Maybe some script or something ???

Comment: Yes.  A script or something will work.

Comment: Can You share with me this script? Please ?

Comment: The site is for professional IT administrators, who tend not to simply ask for scripts to be handed to them.  To be fair, I was being facetious with my comment.  If you want a real answer you need to provide more detail, such as the software distribution tools you use, how the 'PC Tools' product was installed, how your users interact with the domain, and what research you have already done or approaches you have already tried.  Check the [faq] for hints on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a machine with this program installed on it and look for the setup program, then look to see if there's an uninstall option from the command line. If there's a silent uninstallation switch available, you can easily run a login script to try automating this.

If it doesn't support silent and/or command-line uninstallation, you'll have to either script this using a GUI scripting toolbox kit, or give up and go do it by hand, most likely.

If this comes off as vague, it's because that's a very specific product, it may or may not support automated maintenance, and if it was free, it probably was geared for home users and not corporate networks where it would be more management friendly.